# Add ID to an image inside a href PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need to find in all images inside `<a></a>` and add ID to them. It has to be applied only to images inside `<a href..></a>`, not to all images in content.

I tried to use preg_replace but not successfully. It's PHP

```
$content = preg_replace(array('{<a[^>]*><img}'), array(' *add ID to every match *'), $content);
```

Thanks for help
Jakub

Comment: Could you post some example code and HTML?

Comment: Images inside what? It's not clear what you're asking

Comment: Obviously not him, but I'm guessing he meant only images contained within an `<a>` tag.

Comment: images inside link

for example <img src... /> leave as it is, but <a href...><img src..></a> - add ID to that image

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Be sure to include code relevant to your question, including your previous attempts (even if they were not successful). That way, we are better able to understand and answer your question.

Comment: sorry, the text editor automatically removed the main point... i didn't notice that :)

Comment: You should add too a pertinent sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question wasn't as clear as it could be, so I made some assumptions here, but how about something like the below? It uses the image's file name to generate the ID.

Also, I am a little sleep deprived, so I don't promise this will work in every case, etc. But, it worked for my simple example, so maybe it's a decent starting place.

```
<?php
$test = '
    <a href="#"><img src="example-1.png" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="example-2.png" /></a>
    <img src="example-3.png" />
    <img src="example-4.png" />
';

$out = preg_replace_callback(
'|(<a.+?>)<img src="(.+?)\.(.{3})|',
function ($matches) {
        return $matches[1].'<img id="'.$matches[2].'" src="'.$matches[2].'.'.$matches[3];
},
$test
);


echo $test;
echo $out;
?>
```

Which gives:

```
<a href="#"><img src="example-1.png" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="example-2.png" /></a>
<img src="example-3.png" />
<img src="example-4.png" />

<a href="#"><img id="example-1" src="example-1.png" /></a>
<a href="#"><img id="example-2" src="example-2.png" /></a>
<img src="example-3.png" />
<img src="example-4.png" />
```

Edit: as a small note, you'd probably want to do something to the generated ID before using it, maybe replace all the `/` chars with a `-`, for example. I was trying to keep it simple and to the point with respect to finding the right images and adding a reasonable ID here, so I didn't go into that. Your "real" script probably should. Also, two images with the same path and name would have the same ID with this script, which would be a problem. I'd just keep a counter for each one it replaces, and if it finds the same resulting ID again, add a number to the end (so `example` becomes `example1` or whatever). Again, you didn't say how you were deciding what to use for an ID, so I just kept it simple.

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you very much for your help, I know that my question was hard to understand but you got it exactly! This is what I need!
Jakub

Comment: You're very welcome - just be sure to address those warnings at the end of my answer there - this works for a trivial example fine, but any "real world" use will need little more care with the generated ID.